# How to copy paste data based on criteria?

Tags: excel, vba

I’m trying to make a button which on click will filter the database from a column of date for today’s date and copy the whole row of the following and paste them in a new sheet. I’m new to coding so please, help needed.

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()

a = Worksheets("Follow Up").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To a

    If Worksheets("Follow Up").Cells(i, 15).Value = Date Then

        Worksheets("Follow Up").Rows(i).Copy

        Worksheets("today").Activate

        Worksheets("today").Cells(2, 1).Select

        ActiveSheet.Paste

    End If

Next i
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autofilter Macro, then copy visible data ONLY and paste to next available row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903878/autofilter-macro-then-copy-visible-data-only-and-paste-to-next-available-row). Instead of looping, just autofilter and then copy visible cells.

Comment: Can you help me with the code please?

Comment: This is for the next available row? I need the data on new sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `autofilter` (note that the Sub will only look at today's date):

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()

Dim wsFU As Worksheet
Dim wsTD As Worksheet

Set wsFU = Worksheets("Follow Up")
Set wsTD = Worksheets("today")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wsTD.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

a = wsFU.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

wsFU.AutoFilterMode = False

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = "today"
Set wsTD = Worksheets("today")

With wsFU.Range("A1:P" & a) 'adjust to end of data columns
    .AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=Format(Date, "mm/dd/yy") ' adjust to what your date format looks like
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=wsTD.Range("A2")
End With

wsFU.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to get for today’s date only? Like if I click on the button, the previous sheet gets deleted and new sheet is made with today’s data according to date.

Comment: Updated including the the sheet deletion.

Comment: no need for I = 3 to a part? If no can you share it again please

Comment: No loop required for using the autofilter.

Comment: It runs perfectly but the cell width and height settings is still out. Can that be done? Plus I need to copy the top heads row as it is also. Can it happen?

Comment: Updated the code, so it will include the top row. For sheet formatting have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30364064/copying-format-of-one-excel-sheet-to-another-excel-worksheet-using-vba

Comment: my row heads are in row 2. Can it have top 2 rows?

Comment: And start filter from row 3

Comment: no, you can only have one header row. Just switch `Range("A1:P" & a)` to `Range("A2:P" & a)`.

Comment: Done, now the issue I’m having is that paste special function. I’ve pasted the first code but it stucks at first line of the code and says object required.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code. You probably didn't define an object. This should probably be a separate question. Don't  forget to tick the check mark next to my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 0):

## If Today Copy to Worksheet

### The Code

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()

    Dim rngU As Range   ' Union Range
    Dim a As Long       ' Source Last Row
    Dim b As Long       ' Target Last Row
    Dim i As Long       ' Source Row Counter

    ' Source Worksheet
    With Worksheets("Follow Up")
        a = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 3 To a
            If .Cells(i, 15).Value = Date Then
                If Not rngU Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngU = Union(rngU, .Cells(i, 1))
                  Else
                    Set rngU = .Cells(i, 1)
                End If
            End If
         Next
    End With

    ' Target Worksheet
    If Not rngU Is Nothing Then
        With Worksheets("today")
             b = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
             rngU.EntireRow.Copy .Rows(b + 1)
             Set rngU = Nothing
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Output is empty plus if I run watch on the line .cells(.rows.count, 1).value the value is not defined in context.

Comment: @Shaharyar Ali: If you don't have any cell in column 15 with today's date then it is empty. In the Union part, .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1) is not important, it is just gathering any cell from the row where today's date was found. You can freely change 1 to anything, e.g. 15 to remove confusion.

Comment: I understand but I have today’s date in column 15.

Comment: and one more thing, I have 2-3 more dates columns but I want to search date from column 15 only

Comment: @Shaharyar Ali: I've tested the code, it is 100% correct. It is searching only in column 15 ("O") for today's date 03.01.2019 (2019 Happy New year). Do you have as many rows in column 1 as in column 15, because you are calculating the last row in column 1. Maybe it would be better to calculate in column 15: 'a = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row'.

Comment: @Shaharyar Ali: Where is your commandbutton. If it is on a Userform, you have to put the code in the userform's code sheet (e.g. UserForm1). If it is on a worksheet, then you have to put the code in the worksheet's code sheet. Not in a module.

Comment: the button is on a worksheet and I’m putting this code by right click on the button, view code and then under the commandbutton_click()

Comment: @Shaharyar Ali:It is still working. Have you maybe changed the Worksheet names, it is copying from "Follow Up" to "today". May be the commandbutton isn't 6 anymore?

Comment: Yes the command button is 10 now. But it is copying from follow up to today

Comment: It’s not giving me any error but the sheet returns empty

Comment: @Shaharyar Ali: Then it has to be CommandButton10_Click. I would suggest you check all of this we were talking about. I have commandbuttons on sheets and even on a userform. It works fine from any button or from VBA.

Comment: Yes there is commandbutton10_click() under which I have written the code. Is there a way to share a picture here?

Comment: @Shaharyar Ali: Yes, you can edit your answer and in the tools section after the braces {} is the image button and you can upload. While you're at it, upload your current code.